# Simple Powershell script doesn't work when compiled or run as a script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a simple snippet I can run no problems within the powershell console. When I compile it to an EXE, or even a ps1 and run it, it doesn't find the reg value, no idea why.
Here is the code:

```
$User = "Training\Administrator"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssWord" -AsPlainText -Force 
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord 
$creds = $Credentials 
enter-pssession –computername Win7Client –credential $creds
Start-Sleep -s 2
Set-itemproperty “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Citrix\Metaframe Password Manager\Extensions\SyncManager\Syncs\DefaultSync\Servers” -name Server1 -value \\DFSI\CPMStore
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the last lines to:

```
$Pssn = new-psssession –computername Win7Client –credential $creds
invoke-command -Session $Pssn -scriptblock {Set-itemproperty “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Citrix\Metaframe Password Manager\Extensions\SyncManager\Syncs\DefaultSync\Servers” -name Server1 -value \\DFSI\CPMStore }
Return
```

Hope this helps,

Luc